# Get rows from a column per group based on a condition

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

I have a `data.frame` as shown below:

[image]

Basic requirement is to find average of "n" number of "value" after ***certain date*** per group.

For ex:, user provides:

```
Certain Date = Failure Date

n = 4
```

Hence, for `A`, the average would be `(60+70+80+100)/4` ; ignoring `NA`s

and for `B`, the average would be `(80+90+100)/3`. Note for `B`, `n=4` does not happen as there are only 3 values after the satisfied condition `failuredate = valuedate`.

Here is the `dput`:

```
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B"), class = "factor"), FailureDate = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("1/5/2020", "1/7/2020"), class = "factor"), ValueDate = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 2L), .Label = c("1/1/2020", "1/10/2020", "1/2/2020", 
"1/3/2020", "1/4/2020", "1/5/2020", "1/6/2020", "1/7/2020", "1/8/2020", 
"1/9/2020"), class = "factor"), Value = c(10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 
NA, 60L, 70L, 80L, NA, 100L, 10L, 20L, 30L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 70L, 
80L, 90L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could create an index with cumsum after grouping by 'Name', extract the 'Value' elements and get the mean

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 4
df1 %>%
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
   group_by(Name) %>% 
   summarise(Ave = mean(head(na.omit(Value[lag(cumsum(FailureDate == ValueDate),
        default = 0) > 0]), n), na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Name    Ave
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1 A      77.5
#2 B      90
```

Comment: @akrun great. Only caveat here is that if the value of n=3, the mean per group should only consider first 3 values since the FailureDate==ValueDate . In your solution, it creates mean from all the rows after the condition FailureDate==ValueDate is met.

Comment: If  the OP meant only the 4 values then it should be head.  Based on the example, i was not sure because 4 was the largest value among the two groups.  May be the OP meant as you suggested

Comment: @user11397513 thanks, I updated by wrapping with `head`

Comment: perfect. I was here ..test1 <- df[complete.cases(df),]%>% 
  group_by(Name)%>%
  filter(as.Date(ValueDate) > as.Date(last(FailureDate)))%>%
  mutate(mean = mean(head(Value,4)))

Answer (score 3):

You can convert factor dates to the `Date` object and then compute averages of "n" numbers after `FailureDate` per group. Note that "n" numbers should exclude `NA`, so `tidyr::drop_na()` is used here.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(contains("Date"), as.Date, "%m/%d/%Y")) %>%
  tidyr::drop_na(Value) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Value[ValueDate > FailureDate][1:4], na.rm = T))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   Name   mean
#   <fct> <dbl>
# 1 A      77.5
# 2 B      90
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
library(dplyr)

n <- 4

df %>%
  mutate(condition = as.character(FailureDate) == as.character(ValueDate))
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(condition = cumsum(condition)) %>%
  filter(condition == 1) %>%
  slice(-1) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Value)) %>%
  slice(1:n) %>%
  summarise(mean_col = mean(Value))

> df

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  Name  mean_col
  <fct>    <dbl>
1 A         77.5
2 B         90
```